# 'dotnet test' fails with "The active test run was aborted. Reason: "

Tags: c#, linux, unit-testing, .net-core

A `dotnet test` run fails randomly with the following message:

> The active test run was aborted. Reason:

No reason is given and this failure occurs randomly when running on a [Jenkins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins_%28software%29) Linux host. No problems in Visual Studio or command line on Windows.

I was able to find the location of the failure in a couple of functions and the simplified code looks like this:

```
    [Fact]
    public void FailAfterExpiration()
    {
        // Step 1: open session that expires after 30 seconds
        OpenExpiringSession();

        // Step 2: Wait for expiration of the session
        Thread.Sleep(35 * 1000);

        // Step 3: check that failure happened
        Assert.False(CheckSessionState());
    }
```

Sometimes this function works as expected, but most of the time it fails on step 2 after 1-2 seconds of sleep. What could be the reason for such behavior? Is Thread.Sleep somehow causing unit tests to fail?

Comment: I have the same problem (mstest, netcore 2.2, no reason, on linux).
Did found these links, they did not help me, but maybe they can help you.
https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/issues/1699 and 
https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/2817